# Different solutions for seemingly same Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to evaluate the following integral: $$\int_{\left(1-\sqrt{a}\right)^{2}}^{\left(1+\sqrt{a}\right)^{2}} \frac{1}{2\pi x}\sqrt{\left(\left(1+\sqrt{a}\right)^{2}-x\right)\left(x-\left(1-\sqrt{a}\right)^{2}\right)}\operatorname{d}\!x$$

$a\in\left(0,\infty\right)$ is a real parameter.

The radicand is equal to $$\left(\left(1+\sqrt{a}\right)^{2}-x\right)\left(x-\left(1-\sqrt{a}\right)^{2}\right) = 4a -\left(x-\left(1+a\right)\right)^{2}\text{,}$$
and Mathematica agrees on that:

```
FullSimplify[((1 + Sqrt[a])^2 - x) (x - (1 - Sqrt[a])^2) - (4 a - (x - (1 + a))^2)]
(* 0 *)
```

With Mathematica, I get two different solutions:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[1/(2 π*x) Sqrt[((1 + Sqrt[a])^2 - x) (x - (1 - Sqrt[a])^2)], {x, (1 - Sqrt[a])^2, (1 + Sqrt[a])^2}, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals, a ∈ Reals && a > 1}]]
(* a *)

FullSimplify[Integrate[1/(2 π*x) Sqrt[4 a - (x - (1 + a))^2], {x, (1 - Sqrt[a])^2, (1 + Sqrt[a])^2}, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals, a ∈ Reals && a > 1}]]
(* 1 *)
```

If I set $a:=2$, I get

```
Integrate[1/(2 π*x) Sqrt[((1 + Sqrt[2])^2 - x) (x - (1 - Sqrt[2])^2)], {x, (1 - Sqrt[2])^2, (1 + Sqrt[2])^2}, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}]
(* 2 *)

Integrate[1/(2 π*x) Sqrt[4*2 - (x - (1 + 2))^2], {x, (1 - Sqrt[2])^2, (1 + Sqrt[2])^2}, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}]
(* 2 *)
```

But if I integrate numerically, I get the following:

```
NIntegrate[1/(2 π*x) Sqrt[((1 + Sqrt[2])^2 - x) (x - (1 - Sqrt[2])^2)], {x, (1 - Sqrt[2])^2, (1 + Sqrt[2])^2}]
( 1. *)

NIntegrate[1/(2 π*x) Sqrt[4*2 - (x - (1 + 2))^2], {x, (1 - Sqrt[2])^2, (1 + Sqrt[2])^2}]
(* 1. *)
```

What is right and why doe Mathematica evaluate two (seemingly?!) equivalent expressions to different results?

**Edit**
I use Mathematica v. 9.0.1.0 (Win64).

I tried it with blank new noteboooks, different variables, ClearAll and so forth, but I got the above solutions.

Comment: I don't get the same results you get. For instance, the first two integrals you mention both calculate to $1$  on my machine (v.10.1 Win7-64): [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oPRqe.png). Have you tried again in a fresh session on MMA? I think you might have had some spurious definitions polluting your evaluation.

Comment: I have same results as OP on Mathematica 10.0.1.0

Comment: I get the same as @MarcoB, both integrals evaluate to `1` on V10.1, Mac OS.  (The function `Integrate` is updated every version, so including version information is helpful.)

Comment: I get 1 for the first two integrals (10.0.2 on Linux).

Comment: I get different results, (a,1) like @Marco Breitig . On Version 10.0.0.0 Linux.

Comment: Version 9.0.1, the same as you. I get `1` for both of the first two integrals, not `a`, so I would consider this part of the question irreproducible (although apparently it is reproducible with some versions of *Mathematica* 10?). But I also see the difference between `Integrate` giving `2` and `NIntegrate` giving `1`. That, I cannot explain. Note that, when `Assumptions` are not specified, a different answer is produced that evaluates to `1` at machine precision (but not otherwise, in which case it is `Indeterminate`). I am not sure if this is actually a correct answer, but it seems doubtful.

Comment: After a fresh clean installation of Mathematica 10.0.2.0 (Win 8.1 64bit) and in a new notebook I still get the above results (a,1). weird

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: @m_goldberg users  BlacKow and Fabian report getting the same result as the OP however?

Comment: @m_goldberg even if the question contains some mistakes, it also contains enough that is correct and clear to tell that it seems highly likely to be a bug (or maybe two bugs). So, I vote to keep it open.